# How to Bind an Image from an ObservableCollection to View

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-7, data-binding, windows-phone-8

I would like to bind a specific image from an OservableCollection to my View. I am attempting to use LINQ for this, and I believe I am getting the correct image, although the View does not show anything. So far what I have is as follows:

ImagePage.xaml

```
<Image x:Name="photo" Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding}" Margin="12" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"/>
```

App.xaml.cs

```
public static PictureRepository PictureList
    {
        get
        {
            //Gets the ObservableCollection of images from IsolatedStorage
            return PictureRepository.Instance;
        }
    }
```

ImagePage.xaml.cs

```
private void GetImage(string fileDate)
    {
        //if (fileName != null)
        if(fileDate != null)
        {                
            var p = App.PictureList.Pictures.Where(x => x.DateTaken.ToString() == fileDate).FirstOrDefault();
            if (p != null)
            {
                photo.DataContext = p;
            }
    }
```

PictureRepository.cs

```
#region Constants

    public const string IsolatedStoragePath = "Pictures";

    #endregion

    #region Fields

    private readonly ObservableCollection<Picture> _pictures = new ObservableCollection<Picture>();

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public ObservableCollection<Picture> Pictures
    {
        get { return _pictures; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Singleton Pattern

    private PictureRepository()
    {
        LoadAllPicturesFromIsolatedStorage();
    }

    public static readonly PictureRepository Instance = new PictureRepository();

    #endregion

    /// <summary>        
    /// Saves to local storage
    /// This method gets two parameters: the captured picture instance and the name of the pictures folder in the isolated storage
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="capturedPicture"></param>
    /// <param name="directory"></param>
    public void SaveToLocalStorage(CapturedPicture capturedPicture, string directory)
    {
        //call IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication to get an isolated storage file
        var isoFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        //Call the IsolatedStorageFile.EnsureDirectory extension method located in the Common IsolatedStorageFileExtensions class to confirm that the pictures folder exists.
        isoFile.EnsureDirectory(directory);

        //Combine the pictures folder and captured picture file name and use this path to create a new file 
        string filePath = Path.Combine(directory, capturedPicture.FileName);
        using (var fileStream = isoFile.CreateFile(filePath))
        {
            using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(fileStream))
            {
                capturedPicture.Serialize(writer);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// To load all saved pictures and add them to the pictures list page
    /// </summary>
    public CapturedPicture LoadFromLocalStorage(string fileName, string directory)
    {
        //To open the file, add a call to the IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication
        var isoFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        //Combine the directory and file name
        string filePath = Path.Combine(directory, fileName);
        //use the path to open the picture file from the isolated storage by using the IsolatedStorageFile.OpenFile method
        using (var fileStream = isoFile.OpenFile(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            //create a BinaryReader instance for deserializing the CapturedPicture instance
            using (var reader = new BinaryReader(fileStream))
            {
                var capturedPicture = new CapturedPicture();
                //create a new instance of the type CapturedPicture called CapturedPicture.Deserialize to deserialize the captured picture and return it
                capturedPicture.Deserialize(reader);
                return capturedPicture;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// To load all the pictures at start time
    /// </summary>
    private void LoadAllPicturesFromIsolatedStorage()
    {
        //add call to the IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication to open an isolated storage file
        var isoFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        //Call the IsolatedStorageFile.EnsureDirectory extension method located in the Common IsolatedStorageFileExtensions class to confirm that the pictures folder exists
        isoFile.EnsureDirectory(IsolatedStoragePath);

        //Call the IsolatedStorageFile.GetFileNames using the pictures directory and *.jpg as a filter to get all saved pictures
        var pictureFiles = isoFile.GetFileNames(Path.Combine(IsolatedStoragePath, "*.jpg"));

        //Iterate through all the picture files in the list and load each using the LoadFromLocalStorage you created earlier
        foreach (var pictureFile in pictureFiles)
        {
            var picture = LoadFromLocalStorage(pictureFile, IsolatedStoragePath);
            _pictures.Add(picture);
        }
    }
```

Picture.cs

```
[DataMember]
    public string Address
    {
        get { return GetValue(() => Address); }
        set { SetValue(() => Address, value); }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Note
    {
        get { return GetValue(() => Note); }
        set { SetValue(() => Note, value); }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime DateTaken
    {
        get { return GetValue(() => DateTaken); }
        set { SetValue(() => DateTaken, value); }
    }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public BitmapSource Source
    {
        get
        {
            return CreateBitmapSource();
        }
    }

    protected abstract BitmapSource CreateBitmapSource();

    //In the Serialize method, store the Position, Address, Note, and DateTaken properties
    public virtual void Serialize(BinaryWriter writer)
    {            
        writer.Write(DateTaken.ToString()); //writer.WriteString(DateTaken);
    }

    //In the Deserialize method, read the data in the same order you’ve written it
    public virtual void Deserialize(BinaryReader reader)
    {
        DateTaken = DateTime.Parse(reader.ReadString());
    }
```

When debugging, I can see that `p` contains the correct date of an image and that it is not null, but I do not see anything in the view?

Comment: Ironically, the only important code here is the `PictureRepository` which is the only code you didn't post...

Comment: I have added the `PictureRepository` class to my question. The thing is, in another page I populate a ListBox with the entire contents of `PictureRepository.Instance` in ascending order using `Recent.ItemsSource = App.PictureList.Pictures.OrderBy(x => x.DateTaken);` which works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your binding needs to point to the correct property in the `Picture` class which is `Source` in your case.

Try this Xaml

```xml
<Image x:Name="photo" Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding Source}" Margin="12" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
               toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"/>
```